# Copying values from one EditorGridPanel to another with Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a layout that looks like the following:

```
Ext.Viewport{
    Ext.Panel{
        Ext.Panel{
            Ext.TabPanel{
                Ext.Panel{
                    Ext.EditorGridPanel
                }
               Ext.Panel{
                    Ext.EditorGridPanel
                }
                Ext.Panel{
                    Ext.EditorGridPanel
                }
                Ext.Panel{
                    Ext.EditorGridPanel
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each EditorGridPanel is loaded with JSON via ajax, and they each have the same columns.

I wish to have a button in each tab, except the first, the replaces the content of its EditorGridPanel with values from the first tabs grid, either by reloading the values via ajax (fetching the first tabs values instead), or by iterating through the first tabs values and replacing the current tabs values with them.

How is this best achieved? I'm very new with Extjs, so I'm not very familiar with its components and I can't seem to find any way to modify the content of a EditorGridPanel, nor any way to reload its data with a new url. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the method `reconfigure(store, model)`, solves my problems.